# Date input tag helper is not showing the date from database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I use the following code in my edit view, it doesn't show the date from the model.

```
<input asp-for="OprettetDato" class="form-control"/>
```

the property of the model is declared like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0: dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime OprettetDato { get; set; }
```

and the value is passed over in the model

[image: Picture of the model passed]

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Because you were unsatisfied with explanation below, I would like to ask what your question is: *why* or *how to resolve this problem*?

Comment: My problem got solved by removing the DisplayFormat tag from the model -i did this because you got my attetion to the tag in the first place- In that way the HTML5 datepicker could display my date properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that attribute `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` on your model property makes the input tag helper produce `type="date"` HTML attribute, which in HTML5 causes fixed, standard format - see information here: [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

In order to display the field with proper format, **remove** `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` attribute and you will be fine.
Additionaly, in order to have forward slashes in date format, you need to escape them like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:dd\/MM\/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime OprettetDato { get; set; }
```

If you want to have custom date format with datepicker, you need to use some custom JavaScript solution.

**Update:**
Later versions of tag helpers default to the input date type if the model property is a DateTime object. To allow a custom date format ensure that the html input type is text by adding `[DataType(DataType.Text)]`

Comment: I wanted the HTML5 datepicker, and i have (Now) been reading the link you provided. I tried removing the [DisplayFormat] (and keep the Datatype). This actually makes the picker work. in my locale timeformat, this is what i wanted

Comment: You didn't stated that in your question.

Comment: your right, but i didnt realize that was the problem.. :=)

Comment: The format string does not need to be escaped in order to use forward slashes.  The following works: `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0: dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`

Comment: when I remove data type render of the input box is changed to datetime. So this is not the thing that I want. I could not override current text format for the date. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution to my problem

https://forums.asp.net/t/2167833.aspx?Date+control+is+not+showing+value+from+model

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

**ApplyFormatInEditMode = false**

Answer (score 0):

For me it was really confusing, what needs to delete and what not. what I did -

```
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
 public virtual DateTime CalledOn { get; set; }
```

View, I've taken input type="text" not datetime, date or datetime-local

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>@SharedLocalizer["CalledOnText"]:</label>
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="CalledOn">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Date Picket form Bootstrap

```
 $(".date").datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, 
    DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? OprettetDato { get; set; }
```

```
<div class="form-group">
                @{
                    string date = "";
                    if (Model.OprettetDato != null) 
{ date = DateTime.Parse($"{Model.OprettetDato }").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");}
                }
              <label asp-for="OprettetDato" class="control-label"></label>
              <input asp-for="OprettetDato" value = "@date" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="OprettetDato" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Try this.