# DateTime field internal format

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0 app and inside of it a model that contains a DateTime field:

```
[Display(Name = "Date of Delivery"), DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? DateOfDelivery { get; set; }
```

In my Details.cshtml I refer to this field as usual:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateOfDelivery)
```

Depending on where I am, the output of this field differs! If I am testing on my local machine, the output is:

> 20.03.2017

on my on Azure deployed Website, it is:

> 3/20/2017

These different formats bring me into big trouble, as I am using a datepicker to fill the field in my Create/Edit controllers.

I also tried to set the date format explicit:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true), Display(Name = "Date of Delivery"), DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? DateOfDelivery { get; set; }
```

This displayed an uniform date (20.03.2017) on both, local machine and Azure. But still the inputs that are accepted differ. Local:

> 20.03.2017

And on Azure:

> 03.20.2017

What can I do to ensure, that the accepted dateformat on both, my local machine and also on Azure, are the same? I already read a lot of Stackoverflow questions regarding date topics, but none was able to help me.

Comment: Are you accessing Azure website from the same computer? Is there any language/culture specific cookie put into the response from Azure? From what I know, date input format in HTML5 is unchangeable (take look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275423/date-input-tag-helper-is-not-showing-the-date-from-database/42277305#42277305 )

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was one week off. I am accessing the website from the same computer. I was asking myself if it has anything to do with the region I place the website, but I tried Norther Europe and Western Europe and there was no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfDelivery, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")` as in this post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13702321/5939615)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the behavior stays the same.