# How to format Date, Time, Number in ASP.NET Core 2.0, RAZOR Tag Helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm facing problems trying to format DateTime and Numbers in ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0 App using Razor Tag Helpers.

Following the good practices I would like to specify data format at the data model related to the form view.

My Model

```
public class OrderFormModel
{
    public bool IsEdit { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Order Time: ")]
    public DateTime ORDER_LOCAL_TIME { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Order Qty (K): ")]
    public int QUANTITY_K { get; set; }
```

The view:

```
        <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            <label asp-for="ORDER_LOCAL_TIME"></label>
            <input asp-for="ORDER_LOCAL_TIME" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ORDER_LOCAL_TIME" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="QUANTITY_K"></label>
            <input asp-for="QUANTITY_K" min="1" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" />
            <span asp-validation-for="QUANTITY_K" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

The desired formats are

```
12/12/2017 12:23 (can be separated in to two fields as workaround)
```

1 000.145

I've been trying a lot of options but none of them works.
For the number input, I would like when the user enters the value and leaves the input, the format to be applied.

I've been trying:

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm}")]
  (not applied at all)

 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N3}")]
  (not applied at all)

 [DataType(DataType.Time)]
  (applied but seconds, milliseconds and AM/PM present)

 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
  (works for date only field)
```

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATED**

As Stephen Muecke noted [DisplayFormat] applies the format when the page is first rendered. Agree, thanks.
I have initial values for ORDER_LOCAL_TIME and QUANTITY_K properties. DateTime = now for ORDER_LOCAL_TIME and 1000 for QUANTITY_K.

So for example on New Order Action I would like Form View to show formatted initial values for Date with Time (mm:ss only) and Quantity (with thousand separators). The problem is I can't achieve that.

As Stephen Muecke notices format applied when your in the browser and the user edits a value and leaves the input is another story. 
If I use Java Script function connected to the OnChange event of the QUANTITY input, I can format and try to return formatted number as text to the input. But in this case: << jquery.js:7592 The specified value "3 000" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)? >>

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275423/date-input-tag-helper-is-not-showing-the-date-from-database

Comment: Using [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0: dd/MM/yy hh:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] results as empty input mm/dd/yyyy --:--:--

Comment: `[DisplayFormat]` applies the format when the page is first rendered - its server side code. If you want a format applied when your in the browser and the user edits a value, then need javascript (client side code)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke thanks for your comment, I've updated my question to clarify the case.

Comment: AFAIK there is no built in client side support for this in .NET Core. I recommend using globalizejs as the JavaScript support library to handle client input validation. See https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize

Comment: Thanks jcemoller. I'll have a look on the library.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working in ASP.NET Core and have found a solution to this problem that puzzled me off and on for a week (and was not resolved to my satisfaction in any of the forums I found here or elsewhere.)

I did not want to edit the property in the model or in the controller because I wanted the whole date (with timestamp) to be stored in the database.

The solution was to pass `@item.CreatedDate.Date.ToShortDateString()` in the view, now my desired format MM/DD/YYYY on the page where I want limited date information displayed. ("CreatedDate" is my property). Hope that clears up some headaches.

Answer (score 2):

.cshtml:

```
<input type="text" asp-for="Model.StartDate" class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
```

.cs:

```
[Display(Name = "Start Date")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```